# How to Programmatically Determine Supported App Orientations?

Tags: ios, orientation

I am working on a third party library that can go into any app. My library provides functionality that depends on what orientations are supported within an app. I am wondering if there is any reliable, programmatic way to retrieve the list of supported app orientations in any given app. This is important so that I may be able to modify what functionality is available for my library based on what orientations are supported.

**Note:** Considering this is a library, I need to be able to consult *one* reliable place for this information.

Comment: The easiest way would be for the library user to tell you :)

Comment: @David true, and I would opt for that option as a last resort. If it can be done programmatically without having to require the user of my library do more work, that would be ideal.

Comment: The problem is that programmatically determining it involves a lot of conditional cases.  It's not as easy as using UISupportedInterfaceOrientations, because that only establishes defaults that the application may override in a number of different ways on a variety of different operating system versions.

Comment: That is a good point, however I am dealing with a special case in that my library works with its own window, so reliance on how the customer app rotates is a non-issue. All I need to know is if my window is capable of being rotated, which is determined at the project settings level for the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read your *Info.plist* as a dictionary with

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary]
```

And you can easily get the supported orientations at the `UISupportedInterfaceOrientations` key that way.

```
NSDictionary* infoDict = [[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary];
NSArray* supportedOrientations = [infoDict objectForKey:@"UISupportedInterfaceOrientations"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`application:supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiapplicationdelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application%3asupportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow%3a) in the `UIApplicationDelegate` protocol. From your comments it should meet your needs. If the application does not implement that method, fall back to the information in the *Info.plist*.

Comment: Good point! Testing indicates that the value returned from `application:supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:` overrides whatever is specified in the project settings (Info.plist).

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 3.0 :

```
if let orientationArray = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["UISupportedInterfaceOrientations"] as? [String] {
   // Your Code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about Info.plist UISupportedInterfaceOrientations?